# Projection of a hypersurface is dominant

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $F\in \mathbb{k}[x_1,...x_n]$ be a polynomial and let $V(F)=X$ be the set of its  zeros in $\mathbb{A}^n$. We take some point $p\in \mathbb{A}^n\setminus V(f)$. I have just understood what the projection $\pi_p: X\longrightarrow V(x_1=0)$ is: it is a rational map which is not regular everywhere. The problem is formulated as follows: 'prove that the projection $\pi_p$ is dominant'.
If $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible affine varieties and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ - regular function, then $f$ is called dominant if $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$. Also it is if and only if $\mathrm{Ker}f^*=\{0\}$. So, what does 'dominant' means in the context of the given problem with projection? Could you demystify it and give me some hint to prove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dominant still means the same thing. If we have a rational map $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ we can look at the maximal open subvariety $U \subset X$ where $f$ is regular and call $f$ dominant if $f(U)$ is dense in $Y$. So for this problem, try finding where the projection is regular (I think this was discussed in your previous question) and then show that the image of that set is dense in $V(x_1)$. Basically, you have an algebraic condition for the set where $f$ is not regular, and use that to give an algebraic condition for the set that is not hit by $f$, showing it's closed and so the open set that is in the image is dense.